# Flex shrink not working as expected when direction is column

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I've provided the following little snippet and sandbox below. Images shrink to fit as expected when flex-direction is set to "row". However, when I set to "column", the images no longer shrink as expected. I've tried setting the height as per other posts and cannot get it to work.

Try it yourself in the sandbox by changing "row" to "column" under flex-direction. You can change the window size of the sandbox to see how the images change sizes to fit. When set to column, the images just end up being 100% width of the parent. I can't seem to figure this out!!

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.div-item {
  flex: 1 0 50px;
}

.image-pic {
  display: block;
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

React:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import useravatar from "./user.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="cell">
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="div-item">
            <Image src={useravatar} className="image-pic" />
          </div>
         
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Check out the sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-wrap-with-bootsrap-forked-808gd?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: no, its regular behavior, you added `max-height` so it will overlap

Comment: Expected behaviour. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @codemax I'm trying to get the images to shrink to fit within the container when set to column. Currently when it's set to row, the images shrink and fit within the container. If set to column, the images just go to 100% width and stack up outside of the container.

Comment: @NishargShah how to I get it to not overlap and instead just shrink the images within the set side of the container?

Comment: use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @NishargShah thanks for that, but I think that just hides the overflow. I need all elements visible, so they need to shrink to fit within the container. It should be wrapping and shrinking elements in the container as it does when row is set, but with column, it doens't seem to be doing this. Any ideas on that?

Comment: if you want to do it like that your photo will not look like same, else if you want a full image, object-fit then you will get much extra space on the right side

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so I might be wrong but my idea to fix your problem is when you give a certain **width** and **height** to your image parent div you can control them. So with this way you can avoid them getting bigger when they wrap.
(Also you use **flex: 1 0 50px** but **flex-basis** only excepts **%**)

```
.cell {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex:0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.div-item {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```